# Use Tfs client dll without Visual Studio for Dot net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, dll, tfs, visual-studio-2015

at the moment i use Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll along with Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll to access the TFS programatically.

I added the dll's to the servers GAC and everything worked fine.

Now that we migrate to dot net 4.5 and visual studio 2015, i tried to update the dll references. In Visual Studio everything works just fine but when i deploy the executable to the server and add the new versions of TFS dlls to GAC i have a dependency  to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.dll and i don't want to deploy that to the servers GAC as well.

So is there a way to access TFS programatically without adding basically half of Visual Studio DLLs to the TargetMachine GAC?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/) to manage the dll.

NuGet Package source:

- [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Client 14.102.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/)
- [Microsoft Visual Studio Services Client 14.102.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client/)